# How can I encrypt my cookie or session to work with phppass?

Tags: php, cookies, bcrypt

I am currently using http://www.openwall.com/phpass/ to hash my passwords out.

The hash results in a different hash even if the same password is entered.

I check the password like this:

```
$verify = $hasher->CheckPassword($password, $info['password']);
```

`$password` is the entered value, and `$info['password']` is the hash in the database.

Right now, I am setting cookies like this:

```
setcookie(user, $_POST['username'], $hour, $path); 
setcookie(pass, $_POST['password'], $hour, $path);
```

Which results in my cookie being password without any hashing. How can a make my cookie more secure that stores my password?

If I can't store them in cookies, where would I store them?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to store the password in a cookie because you really should not do that.

Comment: Thats really **bad** to set pass into cookie. Use sessions instead.

Comment: Would you like to answer the question to use sessions?

Comment: Sessions. These are stored on the server but even in a session you don't need to store a password.

Comment: Aren't sessions only stored until browser close?

Comment: Depends, normally yes, but if you store them in a database it is up to you.

Comment: I am hoping somebody will answer with a solution that uses sessions.

Comment: Solution for what, your question is about encrypting cookies?

Comment: Really, there are plenty solutions/tutorials for sessions. Basicly, sessions provide global array `$_SESSION` which is accessible between requests. Just google `php session tutorial`, thats very basic subject in php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DO NOT STORE PASSWORDS ANYWHERE, ESPECIALLY NOT IN COOKIES.**

To keep a user logged in, use sessions. The *session cookie* just contains a meaningless random id, while on the server side you just need to store the user's id in the session:

```
$data = /* get user record from database based on username */;

if ($hasher->CheckPassword($_POST['password'], $data['password'])) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['userid'] = $data['userid'];
}
```

Nothing more is needed. You do not need to store the password anywhere or repeat this password check. Just look in `$_SESSION['userid']` to identify the user.

Read more about sessions in the manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: But how would I make this session stay among multiple browser open's and browser closes?

Comment: The same way you do with regular cookies: set an explicit cookie lifetime using http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php and setting appropriate session expiry values (http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php).